# Calculate value in listview upon removing item

Tags: c#, listview

How can I get the total value in my listview. In my listview contains the items "Item Name" and "Price". What I want to do is how to calculate the total price for every item that is remove or added in the listview. Ask me if there are needed clarifications to my question. Thanks

```
foreach (ListViewItem item in listview1.Items)
{
     if (listview1.Items[0].Selected)
     {
          listview1.Items.Remove(lvCart.SelectedItems[0]);                    
     }
}
```

Comment: When you say the total price for any item that is removed or added, do you mean, when you add or remove an item, you want the total total of Price of everything that's currently in the list view?

Comment: Yes, that is exactly what i wanna do...

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution

```
 ListView.SelectedListViewItemCollection breakfast = 
        this.listview1.SelectedItems;

    double price = 0.0;
    foreach ( ListViewItem item in breakfast )
    {
        price += Double.Parse(item.SubItems[1].Text);
                    listview1.Items.Remove(item.SelectedItems[0]); 
    }
```